# Codedeploy agent huge memory consumption

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, aws-code-deploy, codeship

this is my really first question here on stack overflow, sorry in advance if it's not 100% clear.
Btw, for the first time today I had a fairly serious problem due to codedeploy, when I tried to deploy my app with codeship everything seemed ok in the pipeline until in "Waiting for the result of the deployment" stage the deployement broke, so i watched in codedeploy that the distro failed indicating in the * afterInstall * script the following error:

```
Script at specified location: ./scripts/afterInstallScript.sh failed with error Errno :: ENOMEM with message Cannot allocate memory - / opt / codedeploy-agent / deployment-root / b577fbd3-eb6e-431e-8246-db19c4f164a0 / d-4DV4KGIH5 / deployment-archive /./ scripts / afterInstallScript.sh
```

The app did not respond and gave error 503 (db and ssh responded correctly thankfully ...).
Examining the memory occupied by the processes in the EC2 instance I saw that the command ** codedeploy-agent: InstanceAgent :: Plugin ** occupied ** 60% ** of memory available!
I restarted the agent, the memory occupied now was 3%, but once I made a new deployment it returned to 38/40%, this time it didnt fail the build and the app returned 200 but this sudden increase from 3 to 40 worries me enough for the future release , I wouldnt want to restart the agent every time and pray that everything goes smoothly during deployment.

Looking around I saw this thread on github: https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/issues/32 explaining it's a known issue but this doesnt explain why the codedeploy agent occupy that amount of memory even after been restarted ,

Did someone experienced this issue or knows what's going on and how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: A new agent was release today that promises better performance. Can you please check and feedback: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/aws-codedeploy-agent-improved-compatibility-amazon-linux-windows-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately a long running and open issue:

https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/issues/32#issuecomment-521728945

This high memory usage is because rubyzip is used by the agent. There are some suggestions in this thread for optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since it was asked, but for others facing similar issues:

We faced the same issue, codedeploy-agent used to consume up to 50% of memory, until we updated it to the latest version available at the moment i.e. 1.3.1.

You may get latest issues and their fixes related to codedeploy-agent on their [official site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent.html).